# Remove entries of "0" in mySQL table

Tags: mysql

I have a column of ages and there are bunch that are 0. I'd like to remove these without affecting other numbers (e.g., 30).

I thought I could convert the column to text and then do this:

```
update mytable set age = replace(age,'0','');
```

But I think this will also change 30 to 3. What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: You are right in your assumption about `REPLACE` changing `30` to `3`.

Answer (score 2):

If age is a VARCHAR column:

```
UPDATE myTable SET age = '' WHERE age = '0';
```

If it's an INT and nullable:

```
UPDATE myTable SET age = NULL WHERE age = 0;
```

Comment: Does this work if age is `VARCHAR` or also when it is `INT`?

Comment: If it's an INT column, you'll get an error trying to set it to an empty string. What's the column datatype and is it nullable?

Comment: It's supposed to be an `INT` and I can make it nullable (I think)